# Why can't I read a C constant from Golang properly?

Tags: c, go, mingw, hdf5

I am using go-hdf5 to read an hdf5 file into golang. I am on windows7 using a pretty recent copy of mingw and hdf5 1.8.14_x86 and it seems like trying to use any of the predefined types doesn't work, let's focus for example on T_NATIVE_UINT64. I have reduced the issue to the following, which basically leaves go-hdf5 out of the problem and points at something quite fundamental going wrong:

```
package main

/*
 #cgo CFLAGS: -IC:/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.14_x86/include
 #cgo LDFLAGS: -LC:/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.14_x86/bin -lhdf5 -lhdf5_hl
 #include "hdf5.h"

 #include <stdio.h>

 void print_the_value2() { printf("the value of the constant is %d\n", H5T_NATIVE_UINT64); }
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    C.print_the_value2()
}
```

You obviously need to have hdf5 and point the compiler at the headers/dlls and running go get, then executing prints this on my pc

```
the value of the constant is -1962924545
```

Running variations of the above, in how/where the constant is read, will give different answers for the value of H5T_NATIVE_UINT64. However I am pretty sure that is none are the right value and in fact trying to use a type with the id returned doesn't work, unsurprisingly.

If I write and run a "real" C program, I get different results

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hdf5.h"

hid_t _go_hdf5_H5T_NATIVE_UINT64() { return H5T_NATIVE_UINT64; }

int main()
{
    printf("the value of the constant is %d", _go_hdf5_H5T_NATIVE_UINT64());
}
```

Compiling using

```
C:\Temp>gcc -IC:/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.14_x86/include -LC:/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.14_x86/bin -lhdf5 -lhdf5_hl -o stuff.exe stuff.c
```

and running gives me

```
the value of the constant is 50331683
```

And that appears to be the right value as I can use it directly from my go program. Obviously I want to be able to use the constants instead. Any idea why this could be happening?

Extra info following comments below:

I looked for the definition of H5T_NATIVE_UINT64 in the hdf5 headers and see the following

```
c:\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.8.14_x86\include>grep H5T_NATIVE_UINT64 *
H5Tpkg.h:H5_DLLVAR size_t H5T_NATIVE_UINT64_ALIGN_g; 
H5Tpublic.h:#define H5T_NATIVE_UINT64 (H5OPEN H5T_NATIVE_UINT64_g)
H5Tpublic.h:H5_DLLVAR hid_t H5T_NATIVE_UINT64_g;
```

The whole header is here

http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/prev-releases/hdf5-1.8.14/src/unpacked/src/H5Tpublic.h

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me how the constant H5T_NATIVE_UINT64 is defined?

Comment: Looking through the headers, I get this

`c:\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.8.14_x86\include>grep H5T_NATIVE_UINT64 *
H5Tpkg.h:H5_DLLVAR size_t       H5T_NATIVE_UINT64_ALIGN_g;

H5Tpublic.h:#define H5T_NATIVE_UINT64           (H5OPEN H5T_NATIVE_UINT64_g)

H5Tpublic.h:H5_DLLVAR hid_t H5T_NATIVE_UINT64_g;`

Comment: Your comment is hard to read. Would you mind adding this information to your question? There is an “edit” button below it. Please add as much information as possible, including all type and relevant macro definitions.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that

Comment: FYI tested this on Linux and the problem does not occur. Prints `50331683`. Also make sure to use `%u` instead of `%d` when dealing with unsigned integers. It would be nice to have a look into the generated code. Use `go build -work` to get the location.

Comment: Works on my Mac too. Since C is working but not cgo, could it be that one is using the shared library and the other the static one and one of them is somehow broken? Can you try to replace your LDFLAGS with the full paths to the static libraries for instance?

Comment: Would be interested to hear if it works on another Win7 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H5T_NATIVE_UINT64 is NOT a constant but a #define that ultimately evaluates to `(H5Open(), H5T_NATIVE_UINT64_g)`, which cgo does not understand.

It's easy to check by turning on debug output on gcc's preprocessor:

```
gcc -E -dM your_test_c_file.c | grep H5T_NATIVE_UINT64
```

Result:

```
#define H5T_NATIVE_UINT64 (H5OPEN H5T_NATIVE_UINT64_g)
```

Now the same for H5OPEN:

```
gcc -E -dM test_go.c | grep '#define H5OPEN'
```

gives:

```
#define H5OPEN H5open(),
```

Right now, cgo does understand simple integer constant defines like `#define VALUE  1234`, or anything that the gcc preprocessor will turn into an integer constant. See the function `func (p *Package) guessKinds(f *File)` in `$GOROOT/src/cmd/cgo/gcc.go`.

Comment: So why does it appear to work on Linux? Or doesn't it? Does this mean using hdf5 from golang is doomed?

Comment: cgo cannot evaluate non constant #defines on *any* platform. Using hdf5 from Go is not doomed, you just need to find/write a Go wrapper that does provide a proper Go style API with no funny #defines. You can also give [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) a try. BTW, the define you mention generates a func call followed by a variable... I guess the variable value is used as the value of the pseudo-expression that the #define is supposed to represent. What kind of API is that? Have you looked at the amount of warnings generated when you compiled the hdf5 libs? I wouldn't touch it with a poking stick.

Comment: OK thanks for the input! Well that package is the only one out there for go/hdf5. I guess I will stick with good old csv files until I can figure out a better way.