# How do I access a C constant in Rust?

Tags: c, rust

I am trying to use a C constant in Rust. Here is a portion of the C code:

```
#define INT_CANCEL 2
```

In Go, I can do something like this:

```golang
return C.INT_CANCEL
```

How would I do something similar in Rust?

I've tried something like

```
#[link(name = "name_of_lib")]
extern {
    int INT_CANCEL
}
```

But that doesn't compile.

Comment: That's not a constant, but a preprocessor macro. C does not have symbolic constants other than _enum-constants_.

Comment: See also [Convert simple C #define's into Rust constants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33529030/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no Gopher, but **Go** doesn't understand C `#define`s either. Instead, [**cgo** does](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/01/18/cgo-is-not-go) (at least [some subsets of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28442524/155423)).

The best and simplest option is copy the value into your program. Note that you *have to define a size*:

```
const INT_CANCEL: u8 = 2;
```

You could also create a macro if you really needed to be able to wait for the type to be decided at runtime, but that's not common.

You could also create [a build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) that [compiles some C code](https://crates.io/crates/gcc) that includes the header and prints out the appropriate Rust code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myheader.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("const INT_CANCEL: u8 = %d;\n", INT_CANCEL);

  return 0;
}
```

That Rust code can then be included back into your project.

---

You may also try to modify [rust-bindgen](https://github.com/Yamakaky/rust-bindgen) so that does something similar to cgo and attempts to automatically create these constants.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "The best and simplest option is copy the value into your program." That's what I was thinking, I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.